# Magento 2 : tabs positioning before/after not working

Tags: magento2, layout, tabs

I created a custom tab extending `catalog_product_view.xml` and now I don't know how to order my custom tab, it's displayed the first by default. I want to be displayed after the "Details" tab for example but it's not working the `after` neither `before` instructions.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom"
                   template="Vendor_Module::product/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

What am I doing wrong? The "Details" tab is named `product.info.description` right?

I found some solutions, but all consist rewriting all tabs and ordering as you want, but I think it has to be better solutions because rewriting the structure, what will happen if another extension does the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your block first like this

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom" template="Vendor_Module::product/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info">
      <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom tab</argument>
      </arguments>
</block>
```

and then move the same like this

```
<move element="custom.tab" destination="product.info.details" after="product.info.description" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For Change position of Tabbing in details page, Using xml configuration file after or before attribute not help in this case.

You can see more information from here : [Change order of Tabs on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110796/change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page)

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 does not provide any sort order for tab, you can achieve using sequence tag into module.xml file.

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Review" />
</sequence>
```

After that you need to run setup:upgrade command