# How to add my custom product attribute in Description Tab?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add my custom attribute inside the Description tab how can i add? Find the code of core file,they called the `getDescription` function how can i append my custom attribute inside that help me guys.I don't want separate tab i want inside the description tab only.

```
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get access to another attribute or data for the description tab only, it would be probably best to create a new template and remove the existing description tab.

So in you theme create these 2 files (Rename if necessary)

Magento_Catalog

--templates

-- -- product

-- -- -- attribute-description.phtml

-- layout

-- -- catalog_product_view.xml

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true"/>

            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description." template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute-description.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>

    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

**attribute-description.phtml**

```
    <?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_className ?>">
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeLabel ?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>

    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku');?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, all I have added is the below snippet. This fetches the SKU, so just replace with whatever attribute you wish to add in.

productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku');?>

Note: All I've done here is separate the description block to use a custom template instead of the generic attribute template.

In using this new template, your tab order will be incorrect, you can probably just remove the other tabs and add the tabs in your custom xml, or you can customise the tab template to incorporate some order. 
To do that [Change order of Tabs on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110796/change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page) should be a good starting point.

Hope this helps.