# Magento 2 - Create product tab that displays custom attribute

Tags: magento2

I am using **Magento 2**, On the product detail page, I would like to create a new tab next to the description tab named 'downloads'.

I have created a attribute with text area named pdf_download to display what items that come with a product.

I have idea about Magento 1 but on Magento 2, I am totally new. Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Product"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="downloads.tab" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::product/view/details/downloads_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Downloads</argument>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 4. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details/downloads_tab.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getData('pdf_download'); ?>
```

> 5. app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>

        <?php $tabPriority = array(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
            <?php $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name); ?>
            <?php $priority = $block->getChildData($alias,'priority') ? $block->getChildData($alias,'priority') : '9'; ?>
            <?php array_push($tabPriority, array($name, $priority)); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php usort($tabPriority, function($a, $b) { return $a['1'] <=> $b['1']; }); ?>

        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($tabPriority as $name): ?>
                <?php
                    $name = $name[0];
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Now it shows first tab Downloads, Can you guide me how i can sort tabs? so Downloads come as 3rd tab e.g Details, Reviews, Downloads

Comment: Hi @FarhanAziz, try updated code to set tab's priority. Also, you can change tab priority as per your requirement from "catalog_product_view.xml".

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this code for magento 2.

For magento 2, add custom code in theme files.

1. Create new file custom_tab.phtml in

> app/code/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/

and add this code.

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $product->getData('attribute_code'); ?>
```

2. Edit the catalog_product_view.xml in

> app/code/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/

if not exist copy form core file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/

Original Code:

```
<!-- default code .... -->
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="-">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
<!-- default code .... -->
```

after edit code:

```
<!-- default code .... -->
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="-">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="product/view/custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
<!-- default code .... -->
```

3. Edit the details.phtml file in

> app/code/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/

if not exist copy form core file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/

and replace the code:

```
<!-- default code .... -->
<?php $detailedInfoGroup = ["product.info.description", "product.attributes", "reviews.tab"]; ?>
<!-- default code .... -->

replace with this code

<!-- default code .... -->
<?php $detailedInfoGroup = ["custom.tab", "product.info.description", "product.attributes", "reviews.tab"]; ?>
<!-- default code .... -->
```

**You can change the position according tab name and set manor of tabs.**

4. Finally you can see the result.

[image: custom tab]

Thanks. For any query please contact me.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a free simple module, it display custom tab if attribute exist.
It requires simple code edits:
https://github.com/gsw1011/gianlucascoponi-magento-2-custom-attribute-tabs