# How can i change order of Details tab to first in product detail page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to change order of Details Tab  to very first in product detail page. How can achieve this?

Comment: Please find the below answer that might help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242702/how-can-i-change-order-of-details-tab-to-first-in-product-detail-page/242709#242709

Comment: Here in this its explained very nicely https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134231/52754

Answer (score 3):

In Your Custom theme, you need to extend the `catalog_product_view.xml` file in **magento catalog** module if not extended (added).

in this file add `move` tag to change the tab order.

Like :

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element"  before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

So in your case :

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.details"  before="product.info.description"/>
```

Hope it solves your concern.

### For Magento 2.3.2 (as tested)

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
                <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>    
            </referenceBlock>
```

using **sort_order** arguments to manage order (move tag will not work)