# Magento 2.X: Change sequence of Tabs in Product details Page For Porto Theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I had few tabs in product detailed page and I want to show those tabs in order like Details, Key Specifications, contents Of Package, More Information, Warranty, Reviews 
i didnt write any code and i add extra tabs from amin panel
For reference please find the attached image
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 : Change order of Tabs on Product Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110796/magento2-change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

Inside this file, you can fetch all tabs name using, `print_r($detailedInfoGroup)` you have to get value like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => product.info.description
    [1] => product.attributes
    [2] => reviews.tab
)
```

You have to set according to your requirement in new array before foreach in file,

```
<?php $newOrderTabbing = array('product.info.description',,'reviews.tab','product.attributes'); //custom add ?>
```

add `<?php foreach ($newOrderTabbing as $name):?>`

Complete code in `details.phtml` is like below,

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <?php $newOrderTabbing = array('product.info.description','reviews.tab','product.attributes'); //custom added position ?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($newOrderTabbing as $name): //custom arrayname?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**hope its work for you**

Comment: Is this a correct approach? if you can do the resequencing in XML, why we need to do reprogramming in phtml file? please throw some light, might be I am assuming wrong.

Comment: how to find the tab names

Comment: where can i find this Array
(
    [0] => product.info.description
    [1] => product.attributes
    [2] => reviews.tab
)

Comment: goto app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml path and print_r($detailedInfoGroup);

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3.X, we can use `sort_order` argument in `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` xml config as described below:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

> Reference from
>   [Magento2 : Change order of Tabs on Product Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110796/magento2-change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page)

**Hope this will help.**

Answer (score 0):

Copy "`catalog_product_view.xml`" in your Magento_Catalog module in your theme and look for XML section

```
class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details"
```

This contains all the tabs like description, more information etc. You can change the sequence here. Just lift the sections up and down for re-sequencing and set their sort_order accordingly.

```
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">5</argument>
```

Comment: in my theme file i had catalog_product_view.xml but this class product.info.details is not available

Comment: Copy it from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/layout/catalog_product_view.xml file. It will work.